# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un error al teclear un caracter que no sea "Si" o "No", en Python?

Tags: python, condiciones

Intento mostrar un error si se da como respuesta algo que no sea "si" o "no", es decir, otro tipo de carácter.

Sin embargo, siempre me muestra el "else".

```
print ("Bienvenido al sistema de alamenamiento de datos\nPor favor 
introduzca su nombre: ")
Nombre=input()

print ("A continuacion introduzca su edad: ")
Edad=input()
print ("Gracias por registrar su ficha")

Respuesta = input('¿Desea mostrar los datos almacenados?\nIngrese "Si o No":')

if Respuesta =="Si":
 print("Datos ingresados\nNombre: "+Nombre+"\nEdad: "+Edad)
if Respuesta =="No":
 print ("Gracias por utlizar nuestro sistema") 
if Respuesta =="":
    print("No se ha registrado respuesta.\nEl usuario ha dejado espacio en blanco como respuesta.")
else:
    print("Se ha ingresado una respuesta no valida")
```

Comment: También puedes utilizar **switch case**

Comment: @Youshiro Python no tiene `switch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una estructura de flujo básica es la de utilizar `if-else`. Además, también puedes hacer `if-elif-else`, que consiste en decir "valida esto; si no ocurre esto, prueba otra cosa; si no, haz lo de `else`". Puedes leer al respecto en [`if` Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

En tu caso, al decir en la parte final:

```
if Respuesta =="":
    print("No se ha registrado respuesta.\nEl usuario ha dejado espacio en blanco como respuesta.")
else:
    print("Se ha ingresado una respuesta no valida")
```

Lo que está haciendo el código (tras validar sí/no) es validar únicamente si la entrada es vacía o no. Como no lo está, salta lo que hay en el `else`.

Como lo que quieres validar es si una variable vale "sí", "no" o cualquier otra cosa, toca encadenar las condiciones en lugar de aislarlas, dejándolo en algo así como:

```
if respuesta == "Si":
    # bla
elif respuesta == "No":
    # ble
elif respuesta == "":
    # bli
else:
    print("Se ha ingresado una respuesta no valida")
```

Si simplemente quieres validar que se haya introducido algo y no sea ni "si" ni "no", puedes juntar:

```
if respuesta and respuesta not in ["si", "no"]:
    print("Se ha ingresado una respuesta no valida")
```